# C# Selenium : Test Fails intermittently

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using C# selenium for automating the application. I am facing the problem of intermittent failure on executing the Tests.

Sometime the Test pass & sometimes it fails.

Failure states that element/Frame/Window is NOT available.

I have been using the below code for wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
            IWebElement elementToWait = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {
                return Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("Element ID")); ;
            });
```

Is this inconsistency due to the webdriver wait used ? What is the best practice to be followed in order to avoid this ?

Comment: The use of `WebDriverWait` will resolve timing issues on elements not being in the DOM when `FindElement()` is called. however, it sounds like there are other details in your situation (which you've declined to provide thus far). The exact message from the exception would be a good start. as far as i know there's no code in the .NET bindings, nor any of the browser-specific driver implementations that would cause an exception with a message "element/Frame/Window is NOT available".

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question but the most common reason this occurs in selenium is because an element is not in the DOM when FindElement is called.

There are multiple things you can try...
One thing you should is setting an implicit wait timeout on your driver instance as follows:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
```

This should be done right after you have initialized your WebDriver instance.

The second thing you can try is calling FindBy using Expected Conditions:

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Element ID")));
```

There are several different ExpectedConditions available, you can test them out to see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the code above it.  Are you navigating between pages?

If so, try adding a short sleep before this:

```
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Implicit waits are great, but they tend to have a high rate of failure without a short hard-coded sleep.  Usually it only takes 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you refer is because after 100 seconds, your element is still not appearing on the DOM, please, send us your log, but I am sure it's because of that.

The way that the Implicit/Explicit Wait work it's that after the time you setup, if the element does not exist, an exception is raised with a message of timeout (after 100 seconds in you case).

But again, provide more information please.